# Build and Run an xcode project via AppleScript

Tags: iphone, xcode, applescript

I'm trying to build an xcode project and run it through the iPhone Simulator via applescript. I'm aware of **xcodebuild** but it doesn't let you run the app in the simulator. I've gotten pretty close with the script below...

```
tell application "Xcode"
  set targetProject to project of active project document

  tell targetProject
    set active build configuration type to build configuration type "Debug"
    set active SDK to "iphonesimulator3.0"
  end tell

  if (build targetProject) is equal to "Build succeeded" then
    launch targetProject
  end if
end tell
```

... but the build command doesn't seem to obey the **active SDK** property, it always defaults to the project's base SDK setting (such as the iPhoneOS3.0 instead of iPhonesimulator3.0)

Is there a way to tell the build command to use a specific SDK? I'm using xcode 3.2 on snow leopard.

Comment: You might mention which Xcode version you're using. I had no trouble setting the active SDK via AppleScript in Xcode 3.2.

Comment: I'm also using xcode 3.2, but it doesn't work (unless I set iphonesimulator3.1 to be the base SDK within xcode)

Comment: It appears that these types of AppleScripts no longer work with Xcode 4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the trick... you have to set the SDKROOT build setting. Here is a zsh script I use to find the xcode project within the current hierarchy, build it, and run it via xcode.

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

BUILD_PATH=$(dirname $0)

while [[ -z $BUILD_FILE && $BUILD_PATH != "/" ]]; do
    BUILD_FILE=$(find $BUILD_PATH -name '*.xcodeproj' -maxdepth 1)
    BUILD_PATH=$(dirname $BUILD_PATH)
done

if [[ -z $BUILD_FILE ]]; then
    echo "Couldn't find an xcode project file in directory"
    exit 1
fi

# Applescript likes's : instead of / (because it's insane)
BUILD_FILE=${BUILD_FILE//\//:}

# Find the latest Simulator SDK
SIMULATOR_SDKS=( /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/*.sdk )

SIMULATOR_SDK=${SIMULATOR_SDKS[-1]} 
SIMULATOR_SDK_STRING=$(basename ${(L)SIMULATOR_SDK%.[a-z]*})

if [[ -z $SIMULATOR_SDK ]]; then
    echo "Couldn't find a simulator SDK"
    exit 1
fi


osascript <<SCRIPT
application "iPhone Simulator" quit
application "iPhone Simulator" activate

tell application "Xcode"
    open "$BUILD_FILE"
    set targetProject to project of active project document

    tell targetProject
        set active build configuration type to build configuration type "Debug"
        set active SDK to "$SIMULATOR_SDK_STRING"
        set value of build setting "SDKROOT" of build configuration "Debug" of active target to "$SIMULATOR_SDK"

        if (build targetProject) is equal to "Build succeeded" then
            launch targetProject
        else
            application "iPhone Simulator" quit
        end if
    end tell
end tell
SCRIPT
```

Comment: I would up vote you more if I could because of the "insane" comment.

Comment: It's not insane, it's just how paths were specified in the original Mac OS (whence AppleScript originates).  Note that, opposite to Unix, relative paths are specified _with_ a leading colon (absolute paths without one) and parent paths are specified by an empty segment (_e.g._, "::src" == "../src").

Answer (score 3):

Another option to consider is to use Applescript to launch a shell script that executes the [`xcodebuild`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) program.  `xcodebuild` allows you to specify things like a specific target, configuration, sdk, etc.  I use this all the time when I have to SSH into a build server and rebuild a project.

Comment: I've done that, but it doesn't solve the problem of running the application in the iPhone Simulator. It seems only xcode is capable of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The [iphonesim](https://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim) project gives you a command-line launcher for the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 1):

If the `set active SDK` command does not work as expected, a workaround would be to create another build configuration named "Debug-Simulator" (in Xcode in the project settings), and to set the base SDK in the new configuration to iphonesimulator3.0. This would allow you to select the SDK by selecting the build configuration (if that works in AppleScript).