# AppleScript and Xcode error -10008

Tags: xcode, applescript

I am working on a tool similar to the one described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514302/build-and-run-an-xcode-project-via-applescript) question, to build and run an Xcode project via AppleScript, in order to automate testing.  I am getting the following error message:

`Xcode got an error: The specified object is a property, not an element. (-10008)`

from the line

`set active build configuration type to build configuration type "Debug"`.

Has something changed in AppleScript and/or Xcode that would break this line?  If yes, is there a new way to accomplish the same thing, or at least something similar?

I am using Xcode 4.0.2 on a Mac running OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the problem. You see, Apple rebuild Xcode and it's workings, and some AppleScript code (including this one) does not work anymore.

I don't think that there is a solution, unless Apple releases something. I guess they just expect you not to use AppleScript.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've accepted now. Thanks, Apple. I managed to get the project working with lots of ugly GUI scripting, but I don't like it.